# prevent Aws cognito signup multiple user with same phone number when not verified

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

How can I prevent AWS Cognito from signup multiple users with the same phone number where the phone number is not an alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Pre Sign-up Lambda Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html) to do this custom validation.

Comment: Thanks but Is there any other way, If I don't want to use lambda here ?

Comment: No, there is no other way to achieve this.